# debug and find erroneous record

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This code has one erroneous record in data frame and i want to debug and find that record.
As there were not many rows , i was able to find the erroneous record at df2 - 'value4': [9, 10, 11, 'A'], -  it  had 'A'  and as there was Data type inconsistencies,   it failed with the error - "Column overlap and no suffix specified".

Now when there is 10+ million records in data frame it would be difficult to identify such record, and that erroneous record can come in any position.

to figure such erroneous records, am trying to tweak the code in such a way that that the code itself points out that record.

Code -

```
import pandas as pd

# Create first data frame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
   'key1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
   'key2': ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
   'value1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
   'value2': [5, 6, 7, 8]
})

# Create second data frame
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
   'key3': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'],
   'key4': ['W', 'X', 'Z', 'Y'],
   'value4': [9, 10, 11, 'A'],
   'value5': [13, 14, 15, 16]
})


df1=df1.join(df2)
```

Comment: What exactly defines an "erroneous record"? The type doesn't match? The value doesn't match?

Comment: The type doesn't match

Comment: Doesn't match what? Because `A` in `value4` is a string and the rest of the values are integers?

Comment: I don't get any error when I run your code. Pandas automatically uses `dtype=object` when there's no more specific type for the column.

Answer (score 1):

**1 - Columns inconsistencies**

A function which returns inconsistent columns names (use of a generator) :

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create second data frame
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
   'key3': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'],
   'key4': ['W', 'X', 'Z', 'Y'],
   'value4': [9, 10, 11, 'A'],
   'value5': [13, 14, 15, 16]
})

def find_inconsistent_columns(df):
    for column_name in df.columns:
        if not all(isinstance(value, str) for value in df[column_name]) \
           and any(isinstance(value, str) for value in df[column_name]):
            yield column_name

icols = find_inconsistent_columns(df2) # generator

print( next(icols) )
# 'value4'
```

**2 - Indexes of inconsistent rows**

Once you have the inconsistent column names you can locate the indexes of rows containing string using this other function (you may have several indexes) :

```py
def get_inconsistent_indexes(column_name):
    return df2.index[df2[column_name].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]

get_inconsistent_indexes( next(icols) ) # 'value4'
# Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')
```

So in conclusion, `column_name: 'value4' index: 3`

Answer (score 0):

if you're concerned about having non-numeric values in numeric columns, check with the following for your supposed to be numeric columns:

```
non_numeric_row = df[~df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))]
```

and if you're concerned about having numeric values in non-numeric columns, check with the following for your supposed-to-be non-numeric columns:

```
numeric_row = df[~df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (str)))]
```